# Function to list all tables and fields used in each report

Tags: business-objects

I am looking for an SAP BusinessObjects BI 4.1.5 function that lists all the tables and all the fields used in each report we have.  We have hundreds of reports.

The result of the function would list all the Reports, Tables used in each report, Fields in each table, Type, Description, and Value.

Is there a tool or function that can do this quickly and painlessly?

We are on SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.1 Support Pack 5 Patch 13
Version: 14.1.5.1979.

Thank you!!

Michael

Comment: What type of reports (e.g. Web Intelligence, Crystal Reports)?

Comment: We use Web Intelligence reports.

Comment: Web Intelligence reports.

Answer (score 0):

SAP doesn't make this sort of task easy. You can do it using the SDK if you want to go for a deep dive into technical details and some programming.

Perhaps a better alternative would be to purchase a product like those offered by [APOS](https://www.apos.com/Default.aspx) or [GB & Smith](https://360suite.io/).

Best of luck,

Noel

Comment: Web Intelligence repirts